# Android listview with seekbar | always returning the last position

Tags: java, android, listview, service, seekbar

Im developing a small audio-streaming app. I have 5 items in a `listview` and Each `listview` has a `seekbar` with play-button. But whenever I  click the playbutton of the first row in the `listview`, the `seekbar` progresses on the last row of the `listview`.

Please find my code below :

```
Adapter.java

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.songsinlistview, null);
    }
            seekbar = (SeekBar) vi.findViewById(R.id.seekBar); //seekbar is declared as public static
    String streamURL = "http://xyz";
    ImageButton button = (ImageButton) vi.findViewById(R.id.playbutton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, PlayMusic.class);          
            intent.putExtra("URL", streamURL);
            activity.startService(intent);
        }
    });

    return vi;
}
```

`PlayMusic.java` is written as a service that does the streaming job.

How can i stream the song and show the `seekbar` progress in the same row of the `listview` which has been clicked.

```
*EDITED*
```

As the `seekbar` is public, Im able to access the same from the `PlayMuisc.java`.

Comment: the essential part of code is missing, how do you access the seekbar?

Comment: *As the seekbar is public,...*- public as in `static` as well? If yes then it's normal that is happening because the `SeekBar` reference will point to the last `SeekBar` from the last call of `getView()`.

Comment: @Luksprog ohh.. is there any way to get that thing implemented?

Comment: Don't make the reference static, that is not the way to update a view from a row of a `ListView`(which would be done by updating the data of the adapter(which in your case would hold the current value of the `SeekBar`) and calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`). And as your `Service` most likely is based on that static field from communication you'll need to rethink your logic here too.